# Restricted jQuery in knockoutjs.afterRender when using koExternalTemplateEngine_all

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

My simplified sample is made specially to face the issue I'm talking about.

I have very simple html:

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- ko template: { name: 'templateFromServer', afterRender: afterRender } -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>

function afterRender() { 
    // breakpoint is HERE!
    $("<input/>").autocomplete(); 
};

var model = {};

ko.applyBindings(model, $('#container')[0]);
```

All js libraries references are specified before the code.
The *templateFromServer* template is taken from server (not local html) by using of **koExternalTemplateEngine_all** plugin (which uses also **infuser** and **TrafficCop**). The template itself can be anything, even an empty string. After the template has been rendered the *afterRender* is called back, and inside it I want to use **autocomplete** plugin to update an input field inside template. But for this case even no real input field is needed, just let's create it in memory.
When rendering, the breakpoint inside *afterRender* function is hit twice: first, when temporary message "Loading..." is shown, and second, when all template elements have successfully been loaded from server. Now the point. For some reason, in the second round the **"$"** object doesnt have **autocomplete** extension. Even worse: sometimes it does, other times it does not. Looks like this is *different* **"$"** than the main one.
I killed 2 hours to catch this issue. The only idea that seemes to work is placing

```
var MyJQuery = $;
```

in the main code and then using `MyJQuery` insode *afterRender* to access autocomplete plugin.
Any explanations and workarounds are welcome, thanks.

Comment: Interesting issues. The first one (about `afterRender` firing twice) - was already [mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773824/knockoutjs-afterrender-issue-in-version-2-not-apparent-in-version-1-2-x/8794869#8794869) on SO, try that workaround. As for the second one (`$` and jQuery) - you could use `jQuery.noConflict()` [method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/). Hope that helps in some way.

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin there is no convenient place for effective use of .joConflict in my case. But i've read links you gave me and stated the var MyJQuery = $; workaround is good way to fix the issue. Anyway, thank you for the answer, it somehow helped me :)